# Creating BigQuery Stored Procedure by passing column and table name as parameters

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create BigQuery stored Procedure  that will accept column and Table name as parameters.
This is the running Query:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
 ''' SELECT 
         ''' || (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT "MAX(IF(PROPERTY_KEY = '" || PROPERTY_KEY || "', a.RANK, NULL)) AS " || PROPERTY_KEY)
                FROM `project.dataset.table` x
                )  || ''' 
    FROM   (
          select "1" AS GroupbyCol,
                  PROPERTY_KEY , 
                  rank() over (order by PROPERTY_KEY ) AS RANK 
          from (
                select distinct PROPERTY_KEY 
                from `project.dataset.table`
              ) 
       ) a GROUP BY GroupbyCol 
''')
```

I tried creating stored procedure as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `project.dataset.test_stored_procedure_ne`
(table_name STRING, 
destination_table STRING, 
row_ids STRING, 
pivot_col_name STRING, 
pivot_col_value STRING, 
aggregation STRING)

BEGIN
  DECLARE header STRING;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
"SELECT 
         ''' || (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT "MAX(IF(@pivot_col_name = '" || @pivot_col_name || "', a.RANK, NULL)) AS " || @pivot_col_name)
                FROM `table_name` x
                )  || ''' 
    FROM   (
          select "1" AS GroupbyCol,
                  @pivot_col_name , 
                  rank() over (order by @pivot_col_name ) AS RANK 
          from (
                select distinct @pivot_col_name 
                from `table_name`
              ) 
       ) a GROUP BY GroupbyCol 
") header 
USING pivot_col_name AS pivot_col_name

END;
```

Calling SP as :

```
CALL `project.dataset.test_stored_procedure_ne`(
   'project.dataset.InputTbl'  #table_name
  , 'project.dataset.outputTbl'  #destination_table
  , 'Id' #row_id
  , 'PROPERTY_KEY' # column name
  , 'PROPERTY_VALUE' #column value
  , 'MAX' #aggregation if any
);
```

Getting Error as :

```
Error validating procedure body (add OPTIONS(strict_mode=false) to suppress): Query error: Invalid value: Table name "table_name" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.
```

Please explain how and when to put quotes which I believe am misplacing

Comment: did you specify the dataset-name ? you should be querying from `project-id.dataset_id.table_name` or `dataset_id.table_name`

Comment: I noticed that you're not passing the table name to the query , and the execute immediate parentheses not closed ,

Comment: I am passing table_name while calling procedure using CALL() , the first parameter is 'project.dataset.InputTbl'

Comment: @Felipe  Could you help  as you have worked on Stored Procedure

Comment: looks like your trying to reproduce what is already available  - see **How-to** in [Easy pivot() in BigQuery, in one step](https://towardsdatascience.com/easy-pivot-in-bigquery-one-step-5a1f13c6c710) . From that article, I would expected you will realize that you need to use `"||table_name||"` instead of just `table_name` in **FROM \`table_name\`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please explain how and when to put quotes which I believe am misplacing

You have below in few places

```
FROM `table_name`
```

Just replace those with below

```
FROM `"||table_name||"`
```