# How to pass a table name as a parameter in BigQuery procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I am trying to build bigquery stored procedure where I need to pass the table name as a parameter. My code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `MKT_DS.PXV2DWY_CREATE_PROPERTY_FEATURES` (table_name STRING)

BEGIN
      ----step 1
      CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `MKT_DS.PXV2DWY_CREATE_PROPERTY_FEATURES_01` AS 
      SELECT DISTINCT XX.HH_ID, A.ECR_PRTY_ID, XX.ANCHOR_DT
      FROM table_name XX 
      LEFT JOIN 
            (  
            SELECT DISTINCT HH_ID, ECR_PRTY_ID
            FROM `analytics-mkt-cleanroom.Master.EDW_ECR_ECR_MAPPING`
            WHERE  HH_ID NOT LIKE 'U%'
            AND ECR_PRTY_ID IS NOT NULL
            )A
            ON XX.HH_ID = A.HH_ID----one (HH) to many (ecr) 
      ;
 
 END;


CALL MKT_DS.PXV2DWY_CREATE_PROPERTY_FEATURES(`analytics-mkt-cleanroom.MKT_DS.Home_Services_Multi_Class_Aesthetic_Baseline_Final_Training_Sample`);
```

I followed a couple of similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73929733/big-query-stored-procedure-error-with-table-name-as-a-parameter) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711064/creating-bigquery-stored-procedure-by-passing-column-and-table-name-as-parameter), tried writing an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` version of the above but not able to work out the right syntax.

I think issue is; the `SELECT` statement in my code is selecting multiple columns `XX.HH_ID, A.ECR_PRTY_ID, XX.ANCHOR_DT` and the `EXECUTIVE IMMEDIATE` setup is meant to work only for one column. But I'm not sure. Please advise. Thank you.

I am basically trying to write stored procedures for data pipeline building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope below is helpful.

1. pass a parameter as a string.

```sql
CALL MKT_DS.PXV2DWY_CREATE_PROPERTY_FEATURES(`analytics-mkt-cleanroom.MKT_DS.Home_Services_Multi_Class_Aesthetic_Baseline_Final_Training_Sample`);
-->
CALL MKT_DS.PXV2DWY_CREATE_PROPERTY_FEATURES('analytics-mkt-cleanroom.MKT_DS.Home_Services_Multi_Class_Aesthetic_Baseline_Final_Training_Sample');
```

2. use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` since a table name can't be parameterized as a variable in a query.

```
      ----step 1
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
      CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `MKT_DS.PXV2DWY_CREATE_PROPERTY_FEATURES_01` AS 
      SELECT DISTINCT XX.HH_ID, A.ECR_PRTY_ID, XX.ANCHOR_DT
      FROM `%s` XX 
      LEFT JOIN 
            (  
            SELECT DISTINCT HH_ID, ECR_PRTY_ID
            FROM `analytics-mkt-cleanroom.Master.EDW_ECR_ECR_MAPPING`
            WHERE  HH_ID NOT LIKE 'U%%'
            AND ECR_PRTY_ID IS NOT NULL
            )A
            ON XX.HH_ID = A.HH_ID----one (HH) to many (ecr) 
      ;
  """, table_name);
```

3. escape `%` in a format string with additional `%`

```sql
LIKE 'U%'
-->
LIKE 'U%%'
```

- see [PARSE_DATE not working in FORMAT() in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292980/parse-date-not-working-in-format-in-bigquery)